# Correct way of returning angular observable boolean?

Tags: angular

I am facing problems returning observable boolean value in the following method.

```js
  isPresent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    let obsA = this.isMsgAPresent$() // return list of Message objects
      .pipe(map(msgs => msgs != null && msgs.length > 0))
    let obsB = this.isMsgBPresent$() // return list of Message objects
      .pipe(map(b => b?.msgs.some(m => this.isTriggered(m))))
    return obsA || obsB
  }
```

this was working before in angular 12 but after updating to the latest depedencies it started evaluating obsB to null. So I am wondering what is the possible reason that it was working before and not now? Any Idea what changed and a possible alternate soultion would help me debug my problem.

Comment: What exactly is the failure? Please add some info such as what `this.isMsgAPresent$()` is returning etc.

Comment: Is baB supposed to be obsB?

Comment: obsA will always be truthy in itself (it's an observable object), even if the emitted value is null. So `obsA || baB` makes no sense.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible for this function to return null. `pipe` returns an object, and if `pipe` does not exist you will get a runtime error. The function will always return `obsA` which is guaranteed to be an object if there is no error. When you say "it started evaluating to null" what exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to construct a new observable and map all boolean values into a single boolean value.

```js
import {forkJoin, map} from "rxjs";

...

isPresent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return forkJoin([this.isMsgAPresent$(), this.isMsgBPresent$()]).pipe(
        map(([first, second]) => first || second)
    )
}
```

You may have a look at [this Stackblitz](https://rxjs-mapping-playground-qbm4ah.stackblitz.io) where this code runs within your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `forkJoin` as was mentioned in the other answer might not be sufficient if you want to test every value emitted by the two observables.
`forkJoin` will emit only the last values from both observables.

i.e. if you have something like
`forkJoin([of(1, 2), of(3, 4)])` the result will be `[2, 4]`.

If you want to test every value you can use `concatMap` or even `mergeMap` because you don't care about the order of emissions.